# Is there a simple proof of the following Identity for $\sum_{k=m-1}^l(-1)^{k+m}\frac{k+2}{k+1}{\binom l k}\binom{k+1}m$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

While studying the behaviour of umbilic points on Weingarten surfaces I discovered that the following combinatorial identity must be true.

For all $l,m\in{\mathbb N}$ with $l\geq m-1\geq0$ the following holds:
$
\sum_{k=m-1}^l(-1)^{k+m}\frac{k+2}{k+1}{l \choose k}{k+1 \choose m}=
\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}
                  0&if& l>m\\
                  1&if& l=m\\
                  -1-\frac{1}{l+1} &if& l=m-1
                \end{array}
              \right.
$

Improbable as it at first appears, it is easy to check the second and third options are true, and I have computer-checked and found it is true for all $l,m\leq 60$. Perhaps it is well-known or has an easy proof. Either would be good to know.

Comment: The second ($l=m$) and third ($l=m-1$)  identity consist of two respectively one term in the sum, so checking is obvious. So do I understand it correctly that you are asking only for the first case ($l >m$)? (It is not clear for me from your wording.)

Comment: A starting point for the identity in the case $l >m$ could be the binomial inversion $\sum_{k=m}^n (-1)^{k-m} \binom{k}{m} \binom{n}{k} = \delta_{mn}$ (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/beautiful-identity-sum-k-mn-1k-m-binomkm-binomnk-delta)

Comment: The first case is easy as the sum is the $l$th difference of a polynomial of degree $m$.

Comment: @Andreas Rüdinger yes the case $l>m$ is what needs a proof.

Comment: @IraGessel's remark should also apply to the other cases, since the $m+k $-th finite difference of an $m $-th degree polynomial for small $k$ should be easily computable from its highest $k+1$ coefficients.

Comment: @Ira Gessel I'm not sure I understand your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Brendan Guilfoyle If $P(k)$ is a polynomial in $k$ of degree less than $l$ then
 $$\sum_{k=0}^l (-1)^k \binom lk P(k) = 0.$$
 In your sum, we can write $\frac{k+2}{k+1}\binom{k+1}{m}$ as $P(k)= \frac{k+2}{m}\binom{k}{m-1}$, a polynomial in $k$ of degree $m$, and the sum $\sum_{k=m-1}^l$ can be replaced with $\sum_{k=0}^l$, since the additional terms are all zero. 

For a brief discussion of differences of polynomials, see https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h90529. For a slightly more detailed discussion, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05988, pp. 13--14.

Comment: Incidentally, the sum can also be evaluated by Vandermonde's theorem, though this is overkill.

Comment: As a side note (not directly related to mathematical side of the question) I see that you created 3 new tags in this question. Perhaps some of already existing tags might be suitable here, for example, ([tag:combinatorial-identities]) or ([tag:binomial-coefficients]). (Maybe somebody will suggest other suitable tags.) If some further discussion of tags is needed, feel free to drop a line [in this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2017/8/6).

Comment: @IraGessel Thank you for your comments. I have the proo now. I have posted a second question of a similar type, that arose in the same context:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278074/is-there-a-simple-proof-of-the-following-identity-part-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> We obtain for $l,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $0\leq m-1 \leq l$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=m-1}^{l}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{k+m}\frac{k+2}{k+1}\binom{l}{k}\binom{k+1}{m}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=m-1}^l(-1)^{k+m}(k+2)\binom{l}{k}\binom{k}{m-1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{m}\binom{l}{m-1}\sum_{k=m-1}^l(-1)^{k+m}(k+2)\binom{l-m+1}{k-m+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{m}\binom{l}{m-1}\sum_{k=0}^{l-m+1}(-1)^{k+1}(k+m+1)\binom{l-m+1}{k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{m+1}{m}\binom{l}{m-1}\sum_{k=0}^{l-m+1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{l-m+1}{k}\\
> &\qquad+\frac{l-m+1}{m}\binom{l}{m-1}\sum_{k=1}^{l-m+1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{l-m}{k-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=-\frac{m}{m+1}\binom{l}{m-1}[[l=m-1]]\\
> &\qquad+\frac{l-m+1}{m}\binom{l}{m-1}\sum_{k=0}^{l-m}(-1)^k\binom{l-m}{k}\tag{5}\\
> &=\left(-1-\frac{1}{m}\right)[[l=m-1]]+\frac{l-m+1}{m}\binom{l}{m-1}[[l=m]]\tag{6}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\left(-1-\frac{1}{m}\right)[[l=m-1]]+1[[l=m]]}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity
  $$\binom{p+1}{q+1}=\frac{p+1}{q+1}\binom{p}{q}$$
- In (2) we use the binomial identity
  $$\binom{p}{q}\binom{q}{r}=\binom{p}{r}\binom{p-r}{q-r}$$
- In (3) we shift the index of the sum to start with $k=0$.
- In (4) we split the sum and work similarly as in (1).
- In (5) we do some simplifications regarding $(1-1)^{l-m+1}$ using *Iverson brackets*. We also shift the index of the sum again.
- In (6) we do a similar job as in (5).

Comment: The context in which this arose is now in a paper on the arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.00580

Comment: @BrendanGuilfoyle: Interesting paper (but somewhat beyond my scope) and a great pleasure to see my contribution was useful. :-) Many thanks for taking my proof into your paper and citing my name. Kind regards,