# Is there a simple proof of the following binomial Identity (part 2)?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

This is a related question to the one I posted on MO earlier:

[Is there a simple proof of the following Identity for $\sum_{k=m-1}^l(-1)^{k+m}\frac{k+2}{k+1}{\binom l k}\binom{k+1}m$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275214/is-there-a-simple-proof-of-the-following-identity-for-sum-k-m-1l-1km?noredirect=1#comment679902_275214)

It arose in the same context: the degeneracy of umbilic points on Weingarten surfaces.

For all $l,m\in{\mathbb N}$ with $l\geq m\geq0$ the following identities appear to hold:
\begin{eqnarray}
&(1-(2m+1)(m+1)){\textstyle{{l+1 \choose m}}}\nonumber\\
+\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{l+1}&(-1)^{\scriptstyle{{k+m}}}{\textstyle{{l+1 \choose k}}}\left[(1-(2k+1)(m+2)){\textstyle{\frac{2m+2}{2k+1}{k \choose m+1}}}+(1-(2k+1)(m+1)){\textstyle{\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}{k \choose m}}}\right]\nonumber\\
&=
\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}
                  0&if& l>m\\
                  2(l+1)(l+2) &if& l=m
                \end{array}.
              \right.\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

Obviously the $l=m$ case is trivial (I include it for completeness). So, any suggestions for a proof of this?

Comment: First step: The beauty inside the square brackets simplifies to $\left(m-4k-2km\right)\dbinom{k}{m}$. The second step could be observing that $\dbinom{l}{k}\dbinom{k}{m} = \dbinom{l}{m}\dbinom{l-m}{k-m}$, and of course the $\dbinom{l}{m}$ can be taken out of the sum. After that, I believe you end up with the $l-m$-th finite difference of a degree-$1$ polynomial in $k$.

Comment: That said, I suspect there are typos in the statement. The sum goes all the way up to $l+1$, but the $\dbinom{l}{k}$ kills the $k=l+1$ addend, which doesn't smell of intent to me.

Comment: @darij grinberg - correct and now corrected!

Comment: I don't think you need anything more than Darij's first step. This gives the $(l+1)$th (or is it $(l+1)$st?) difference of a polynomial in $k$ of degree $m+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the hint @darijgrinberg   stated  in the comment section with respect to the *beauty* inside the square brackets we  focus on the sum and

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}}&\color{blue}{(-1)^{k+m}\binom{l+1}{k}
> \left[(1-(2k+1)(m+2))\frac{2m+2}{2k+1}\binom{k}{m+1}\right.}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
> \color{blue}{\left.+(1-(2k+1)(m+1))\frac{2m+1}{2k+1}\binom{k}{m}\right]}\\
> &=\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}(-1)^{k+m}\binom{l+1}{k}[m-2k(m+2)]\binom{k}{m}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{l+1}{m}\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}(-1)^{k+m}\binom{l+1-m}{k-m}[m-2k(m+2)]\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{l+1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{l+1-m}(-1)^{k}\binom{l+1-m}{k}[-2k(m+2)-m(2m+3)]\tag{3}\\
> &=-2(m+2)\binom{l+1}{m}\sum_{k=1}^{l+1-m}(-1)^{k}\binom{l+1-m}{k}k\\
> &\qquad-m(2m+3)\binom{l+1}{m}\left([[l+1=m]]-1\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=-2(m+2)\binom{l+1}{l+1-m}(l+1-m)\sum_{k=1}^{l+1-m}(-1)^{k}\binom{l-m}{k-1}\\
> &\qquad-m(2m+3)\binom{l+1}{m}\left([[l+1=m]]-1\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=2(m+2)(l+1)\binom{l}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{l-m}(-1)^{k}\binom{l-m}{k}\\
> &\qquad-m(2m+3)\binom{l+1}{m}\left([[l+1=m]]-1\right)\tag{6}\\
> &\color{blue}{=2(l+1)(l+2)[[l=m]]}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{-(1-(2m+1)(m+1))\binom{l+1}{m}\left([[l+1=m]]-1\right)}\tag{7}\\
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with OPs claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use @darijgrinbergs simplified bracketed beauty.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity
  $$\binom{p}{q}\binom{q}{r}=\binom{p}{r}\binom{p-r}{q-r}$$
- In (3) we shift the index to start with $k=1$.
- In (4) we split the sum and do some simplifications regarding $(1-1)^{l+1-m}$ using *Iverson brackets*.
- In (5) and (6) we use the binomial identity
  $$\binom{p+1}{q+1}=\frac{p+1}{q+1}\binom{p}{q}$$
  and we shift the index to start with $k=0$.
- In (7) we do some final simplifications and adaptions to better see the relationship with OPs identity.

Comment: The context in which this arose is now in a paper on the arxiv: arxiv.org/abs/1709.00580

Answer (score 7):

Let $l$ and $m$ be two integers such that $l\geq m\geq0$. You want me to prove
the identity
\begin{align}
& \left(  1-\left(  2m+1\right)  \left(  m+1\right)  \right)  \dbinom{l+1}
{m}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\dbinom{l+1}{k}Q\left(
k,m\right)  \nonumber\\
& =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }l>m;\\
2\left(  l+1\right)  \left(  l+2\right)  , & \text{if }l=m
\end{cases}
,\tag{1}\label{g-pf.1}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align*}
Q\left(  k,m\right)    & =\left(  1-\left(  2k+1\right)  \left(  m+2\right)
\right)  \dfrac{2m+2}{2k+1}\dbinom{k}{m+1}\\
& +\left(  1-\left(  2k+1\right)  \left(  m+1\right)  \right)  \dfrac
{2m+1}{2k+1}\dbinom{k}{m}.
\end{align*}

Set $x=-2m-4$ and $y=-2m^{2}-3m$. Then, $y=1-\left(  2m+1\right)  \left(
m+1\right)  $.

Every nonnegative integer $k$ satisfies $\dbinom{k}{m+1}=\dfrac{k-m}
{m+1}\dbinom{k}{m}$ (by straightforward computation), and therefore the
definition of $Q\left(  k,m\right)  $ rewrites as
\begin{align}
Q\left(  k,m\right)    & =\left(  1-\left(  2k+1\right)  \left(  m+2\right)
\right)  \dfrac{2m+2}{2k+1}\cdot\dfrac{k-m}{m+1}\dbinom{k}{m}\nonumber\\
& +\left(  1-\left(  2k+1\right)  \left(  m+1\right)  \right)  \dfrac
{2m+1}{2k+1}\dbinom{k}{m}\nonumber\\
& =\left(  m-4k-2km\right)  \dbinom{k}{m}\tag{3}\label{g-pf.3}
\end{align}
(after some straightforward computation).

On the other hand, it is known that any three integers $a$, $b$ and $c$
satisfying $b\geq c$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
\dbinom{a}{b}\dbinom{b}{c}=\dbinom{a}{c}\dbinom{a-c}{b-c}\tag{5}\label{g-pf.5}
\end{equation}
(this is the so-called *trinomial revision formula*, in Knuth's terminology).
Now,
\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\dbinom{l+1}{k}
\underbrace{Q\left(  k,m\right)  }_{\substack{=\left(  m-4k-2km\right)
\dbinom{k}{m}\\\text{(by \eqref{g-pf.3})}}}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\dbinom{l+1}{k}\left(
m-4k-2km\right)  \dbinom{k}{m}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\left(  m-4k-2km\right)
\underbrace{\dbinom{l+1}{k}\dbinom{k}{m}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{l+1}{m}
\dbinom{l+1-m}{k-m}\\\text{(by \eqref{g-pf.5}, applied to }a=l+1\text{,
}b=k\text{ and }c=m\text{)}}}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\left(  m-4k-2km\right)
\dbinom{l+1}{m}\dbinom{l+1-m}{k-m}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{l+1-m}\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m+m}}_{=\left(
-1\right)  ^{k}}\underbrace{\left(  m-4\left(  k+m\right)  -2\left(
k+m\right)  m\right)  }_{\substack{=xk+y\\\text{(by straightforward
computation)}}}\dbinom{l+1}{m}\dbinom{l+1-m}{k}\nonumber\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{here, we have substituted }k+m\text{ for
}k\text{ in the sum}\right)  \nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{l+1-m}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\left(  xk+y\right)  \dbinom
{l+1}{m}\dbinom{l+1-m}{k}.\tag{7}\label{g-pf.7}
\end{align}
But
\begin{align}
& \dbinom{l+1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{l+1-m}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\left(  xk+y\right)
\dbinom{l+1-m}{k}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=0}^{l+1-m}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\left(  xk+y\right)  \dbinom
{l+1}{m}\dbinom{l+1-m}{k}\nonumber\\
& =\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{0}}_{=1}\underbrace{\left(  x\cdot
0+y\right)  }_{\substack{=y\\=1-\left(  2m+1\right)  \left(  m+1\right)
}}\dbinom{l+1}{m}\underbrace{\dbinom{l+1-m}{0}}_{=1}\nonumber\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{l+1-m}\left(  -1\right)
^{k}\left(  xk+y\right)  \dbinom{l+1}{m}\dbinom{l+1-m}{k}}_{\substack{=\sum
_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\dbinom{l+1}{k}Q\left(  k,m\right)
\\\text{(by \eqref{g-pf.7})}}}\nonumber\\
& =\left(  1-\left(  2m+1\right)  \left(  m+1\right)  \right)  \dbinom{l+1}
{m}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\dbinom{l+1}{k}Q\left(
k,m\right)  .\tag{11}\label{g-pf.11}
\end{align}
Thus, the left-hand side of the equality \eqref{g-pf.1} is the left-hand side
of \eqref{g-pf.11}.

But it is well-known (and follows, e.g., from the binomial
formula) that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{N}{k}=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }N=0;\\
0, & \text{if }N>0
\end{cases}
\tag{12}\label{g-pf.12}
\end{equation}
for every nonnegative integer $N$. Hence, for every positive integer $N$, we
have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{N}{k}=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }N=0;\\
0, & \text{if }N>0
\end{cases}
=0\tag{13}\label{g-pf.13}
\end{equation}
(since $N>0$). Now, for every positive integer $N$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{N}{k}  & =\underbrace{\left(
-1\right)  ^{0}0\dbinom{N}{0}}_{=0}+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(  -1\right)
^{k}\underbrace{k\dbinom{N}{k}}_{=N\dbinom{N-1}{k-1}}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{N}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}N\dbinom{N-1}{k-1}=N\sum_{k=1}
^{N}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{N-1}{k-1}\nonumber\\
& =N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\underbrace{\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+1}}_{=-\left(
-1\right)  ^{k}}\dbinom{N-1}{k}\nonumber\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{here, we have substituted }k+1\text{ for
}k\text{ in the sum}\right)  \nonumber\\
& =-N\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{N-1}{k}
}_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }N-1=0;\\
0, & \text{if }N-1>0
\end{cases}
\\\text{(by \eqref{g-pf.12}, applied to }N-1\text{ instead of }N\text{)}}}=-N
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }N-1=0;\\
0, & \text{if }N-1>0
\end{cases}
\nonumber\\
& =
\begin{cases}
-N, & \text{if }N-1=0;\\
0, & \text{if }N-1>0
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
-N, & \text{if }N=1;\\
0, & \text{if }N>1
\end{cases}
\nonumber\\
& =
\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{if }N=1;\\
0, & \text{if }N>1
\end{cases}
\tag{15}\label{g-pf.15}
\end{align}
(since $-N=-1$ in the case when $N=1$). Hence, for every positive integer $N$,
we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{N+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\left(  xk+y\right)  \dbinom{N}{k}  &
=x\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}k\dbinom{N}{k}
}_{\substack{=
\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{if }N=1;\\
0, & \text{if }N>1
\end{cases}
\\\text{(by \eqref{g-pf.15})}}}+y\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{N+1}\left(
-1\right)  ^{k}\dbinom{N}{k}}_{\substack{=0\\\text{(by \eqref{g-pf.13})}}}\\
& =x
\begin{cases}
-1, & \text{if }N=1;\\
0, & \text{if }N>1
\end{cases}
+y0=
\begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if }N=1;\\
0, & \text{if }N>1
\end{cases}
.
\end{align*}
Applying this to $N=l+1-m$ (which is a positive integer since $l+1>l\geq m$),
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{l+1-m}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\left(  xk+y\right)  \dbinom
{l+1-m}{k}  & =
\begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if }l+1-m=1;\\
0, & \text{if }l+1-m>1
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if }l=m;\\
0, & \text{if }l>m
\end{cases}
.
\end{align*}
Now, \eqref{g-pf.11} yields
\begin{align*}
& \left(  1-\left(  2m+1\right)  \left(  m+1\right)  \right)  \dbinom{l+1}
{m}+\sum_{k=m+1}^{l+1}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k+m}\dbinom{l+1}{k}Q\left(
k,m\right)  \\
& =\dbinom{l+1}{m}\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{l+1-m}\left(  -1\right)  ^{k}\left(
xk+y\right)  \dbinom{l+1-m}{k}}_{=
\begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if }l=m;\\
0, & \text{if }l>m
\end{cases}
}\\
& =\dbinom{l+1}{m}
\begin{cases}
-x, & \text{if }l=m;\\
0, & \text{if }l>m
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
-\dbinom{l+1}{m}x, & \text{if }l=m;\\
0, & \text{if }l>m
\end{cases}
\\
& =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }l>m;\\
-\dbinom{l+1}{m}x, & \text{if }l=m
\end{cases}
=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if }l>m;\\
2\left(  l+1\right)  \left(  l+2\right)  , & \text{if }l=m
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
(because $-\dbinom{l+1}{m}x=2\left(  l+1\right)  \left(  l+2\right)  $ in the
case when $l=m$ (this follows by trivial computations)). This proves \eqref{g-pf.1}.